# jquery find text of nearest span with a certain class

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to find the text of a span that is close to a div that I clicked. Right now, I'm getting nothing in console.log.

html:

```
<div class="section group">
        <div class="col2 span_1_of_2 photo">
            <img class="person" src="img/mobile/Bill.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="col2 span_1_of_2 details last">
            <div class="quote">&quot;When in the course of human events...&quot;</div>
            <div class="attribution"><span class="person_name">Bill</span>, <span class="person_age">89</span> <span class="person_where"></span></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.person').on('click', function() {
        //get name
        var person_name = $(this).closest('.person_name').text();
        console.log(person_name); //returns nothing
});
```

I haven't seen exactly this question before. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses *up* the DOM and `.person-name` is the descendant of a sibling element. Instead use:

```
var person_name = $(this).parent().next().find('.person_name').text();
```

```js
$('.person').on('click', function() {
  //get name
  var person_name = $(this).parent().next().find('.person_name').text();
  console.log(person_name); //returns nothing
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col2 span_1_of_2 photo">
    <img class="person" src="img/mobile/Bill.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col2 span_1_of_2 details last">
    <div class="quote">&quot;When in the course of human events...&quot;</div>
    <div class="attribution"><span class="person_name">Bill</span>, <span class="person_age">89</span>  <span class="person_where"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was close, but wasn't quite it. But you were right - I had to go up to the parent.

Comment: Sorry, @j08691 - I have two versions of this code, and was using the wrong one to test your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.person').on('click', function() {
        //get name
        var person_name=$(this).closest('div').siblings('.details').find('.person_name').text();
        console.log(person_name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a traversal problem, you have to go up the DOM tree and then search down the DOM tree.
sample:

```
$('.person').on('click', function() {
    //get name
    var person_name = $(this).parent().next().find('.person_name').text();
    console.log(person_name); //returns Bill
});
```

Comment: How is your answer fundamentally different from mine, which was submitted half an hour earlier?

Comment: When I was answering  this question there was no committed answers, by the time I hit the submit button it refresh with 3 answers and saw we had the same solution, and I would say it was couple of minutes I was just testing the code so I don't provide some erroneous answers